# EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE - Crashlytics non-fatal error - http request failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-getx

I am trying to load list of products and I am using CachedNetworkImage (or if I also use Image.network) to display image of that particular product.

I have used Error Builder property so that if image is giving error then show default asset image and it works fine. Until I push another page on top of it then I receive the following in the debug console.

```
I/flutter (21932): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (21932): The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (21932): HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://***.com/url.jpg
```

However, I read somewhere if we are receiving this kind of error then just ignore it as CachedNetoworkImage author also said the same in his last line of document. But the thing is I am also using Firebase Crashlytics to display crashes and errors if there are any.

Thing is I am getting Non Fatal errors because of this exception. So even if 1 user is going through my app then they not gonna see any error on screen but if i go through crashlytics i am getting more than 48 Non-fatal error of that particular user.
[image: Non Fatal Error for Images not found 404 error]

This is my code for displaying the list of product and its image
**ProductTile.dart**

```
import 'package:applicationName/views/product_page/model/ProductModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ProductTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  const ProductTile(this.product);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Get.toNamed("/productDetailPage/${product.prodId}");
      },
      child: Card(
        elevation: 2,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0)),
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "${product.discount}% OFF",
                    textScaleFactor: 0.8,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
                // color: Colors.red,
                child: Image.network(
              product.image,
              errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
                  StackTrace stackTrace) {
                // Appropriate logging or analytics, e.g.
                // myAnalytics.recordError(
                //   'An error occurred loading "https://example.does.not.exist/image.jpg"',
                //   exception,
                //   stackTrace,
                // );
                return Image.asset('assets/images/noimage.png');
              },
            )
 //I commented this to check if same is happening with Image.network() also or not and it's happening in //it too.
                // CachedNetworkImage(
                //   alignment: Alignment.center,
                //   imageUrl: product.image,
                //   placeholder: (context, url) =>
                //       Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                //   errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                //       Image.asset('assets/images/noimage.png'),
                // ),
                ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                product.prodName,
                maxLines: 2,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'avenir', fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Flex(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    // "Some Text",
                    // '₹${double.parse(product.fprice).toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                    double.tryParse(product.priceFormat) is double
                        ? "₹${double.tryParse(product.priceFormat).toStringAsFixed(2)}"
                        : "${product.priceFormat}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        // fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'avenir',
                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: Flex(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    // "Some Text",
                    //
                    // product.price is String
                    //     ? '₹${double.parse(product.price).toStringAsFixed(2)}'
                    //     : '₹${product.price.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                    double.tryParse(product.fpriceFormat) is double
                        ? "₹${double.tryParse(product.fpriceFormat).toStringAsFixed(2)}"
                        : "${product.fpriceFormat}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      // fontSize: 15,
                      fontFamily: 'avenir',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

No matter which page I push after the above page I am still getting that exception in the console.

Comment: is the uri  invalid?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes the uri is invalid and that is obvious because the images are not uploaded for all the products only some images are there for some products which is why i used error builder so that if no image found then use the asset image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good idea to run the app with [`runZoned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/runZoned.html). So this is how you would do it.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runZoned(
    () => MyApp(),
    (error, stackStrace) {
      // Handle errors here :)
      // Check for error from `CachedNetworkImage`.
    },
  );
}
```

Hope this helps :D